# Github Actions Go lambda project different sha256sums

Tags: go, ubuntu, continuous-integration, zip, github-actions

I have Golang aws lambda project. I deploy it on github actinos using terraform scripts.
I have situation like:
Build #1

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 runner docker 14717304 Jan  1  2022 aTest
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  7776780 Jan  1  2022 aTest.zip
```

I do 1 change in some file that is even not imported in any other file and
Build #2

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 runner docker 14717304 Jan  1  2022 aTest
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  7776755 Jan  1  2022 aTest.zip
```

zips sizes are changed but binary not

here is important part of my Makefile

```
build: ## Build Linux binary with path consistent with passed functionction layere (layer) and functionction name (function)
build: resolve-env
    @$(BUILD_FLAGS) ${GOCMD} build ${LDFLAGS} -o ${BINARY_PATH} ${GO_PKG}
    @touch -t 202201010000.00 ${BINARY_PATH}

.PHONY: package
package: build
    @cd ${DST} && ${ZIPCMD} -X -q --latest-time ${ABS_ZIP_PATH} ${function}
    @touch -t 202201010000.00 ${ABS_ZIP_PATH}
```

when I do the same change locally, and run build using terraform or tool called: "act" there is no such change.. only on github actions.
I need to keep the same size, which affects sha256sum ( to avoid deploying each lambda ).
What can be the reason ?

Comment: IIUC, the zip file size is different on your local machine and GHA runner even if the binary size remains the same, right?

Comment: zip file is different on each build on githubactions even if binary size is the same, locally its fine

Comment: Have you verified if the Makefile is not missing any steps on your local dev setup? You can correlate the timestamps after commenting `touch` commands.

Comment: Makefile is the same

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) as a repo? That'll be helpful to understand and iterate.

Comment: Also, did you try using the binary mode `-b` / `--binary` of `sha256sum` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer focuses on the reproducible build of the go binaries.

Though it shows that the go binaries have the same size, I doubt that the contents are different. Please check the hash of binaries to confirm that first.

To get a reproducible build, besides other obvious requirements, you also need to:

1. ensure that the cgo build is reproducible (toolchain, dependencies, etc), or disable cgo. You have set `CGO_ENABLED=0` already (this information is provided by another question which has already been deleted).
2. use the `-trimpath` flag. Maybe the GitHub action will always place the source code in the same directory. To be safe, let's specify this option.
3. set `-buildvcs=false`. By default ("auto"), version control information is stamped into the binary if it's available. This explains why two commits with only difference in the readme file produce different binaries.

References:

- [Go support on Reproducible Builds](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57120)
- [x/build/cmd/relui: ensure fully reproducible builds, including tar.gz/zip archives](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24904)
- [doc: add a documentation page for reproducible builds](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53976)
- [REPRODUCING GO BINARIES BYTE-BY-BYTE](https://words.filippo.io/reproducing-go-binaries-byte-by-byte/)

Comment: thanks, my final version is:
 @$(BUILD_FLAGS) GOOS=linux ${GOCMD} build -buildvcs=false -ldflags "-buildid=12345 -w -s -X 'main.build=2023-01-01T00:00:00Z' -X main.version=1.0.0" -o ${BINARY_PATH} -trimpath ${GO_PKG}

Comment: `-ldflags "-buildid=12345 -w -s -X 'main.build=2023-01-01T00:00:00Z' -X main.version=1.0.0"`, in your real project, the information provided here are read from somewhere that can be used to determine a unique build based on your need, right?

Comment: yes, to have the same hashes if files were not changed so TF will deploy only changed ones